# How to Interagate PayUBiz in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, payment-gateway, payment

Please help me , how to interagate payUbizz in IOS.I follow some link are as follows :

1.https://github.com/payu-intrepos/Documentations/wiki/8.1-NEW-iOS-Seamless-SDK-integration
2.https://developer.payubiz.in/documentation/iOS-SDK-%28Non-Seamless%29/73

But when i download this Non-Seamless sdk, i see it doesn't contain any ui classes in it.So, please provide me datails or any kind of help regarding this.

OR

When i import SDK file in bridging-Header file i am getting error #import "PayU_iOS_CoreSDK.h" file not found.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Link : https://github.com/payu-intrepos/iOS-SDK/blob/master/PayU_iOS_CoreSDK/PayU_iOS_CoreSDK.h

Include this file in your project. This will resolve your problems.
If it still gives you the same error. You have to manually include it your project files.

Comment: Then I think you aren't linking the framework or libraries. Link it and the above solution will work with it.

Comment: I solved this by using this #import"PayU_iOS_CoreSDK/PayU_iOS_CoreSDK.h" instead of #import"PayU_iOS_CoreSDK.h" but problem is i am doing non - seamless payment option that provide own UI for payment but there is no source available in this SDK like PayUMoney.